# Custom control or not in this case?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, controltemplate

I would factor a graphic control, but I do not know how to do it.

I want to create a container control with templated elements.

ex:

```
<MyControl>
   <MyControl.Elements>
     <TextElement Value="{Binding Somedata}" />
     <IntElement Value="{Binding OtherData}" />
   </MyControl.Elements>
</MyControl>
```

The different elements are templates that I have created to always display the same way an item.
In simple example, MyControl will be a WrapPanel, TextElement a TextBlock and IntElement a TextBox. Elements will be WrapPanel's children.

Should I create a custom control for MyControl ?
And a dependency property for Elements ?
How create ElementBase for all templates ?

Thank you

Comment: What? I don't understand a single word of this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply want an ItemsControl.

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.Items>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Somedata}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherData}" />
        </ItemsControl.Items>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want different template for each item. But your sample give me an idea.